# Could Xcode be responsible for button formatting differences?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I've inherited an iOS app the was probably developed in Xcode 4. I'm using Xcode 6, and also have access to Xcode 5. The production executable of the app I'm working on shows buttons with white text and a blue background. However, the code I'm running shows the buttons with blue text and a transparent background.

I normally would attribute this to code or xib file changes.  But the versions I've checked out *should* correspond to the production version. So I'm wondering if perhaps there's something on my machine that could be responsible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on Xcode 5 or 6, then you're building against the iOS 7 or iOS 8 SDKs (unless you hacked your installation).

As you probably know, iOS 7 introduced major visual changes to the SDK, so it's normal for the  app to have a significantly different appearance.

You can verify this by [downloading Xcode 4 here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode%204).

Comment: Thanks, that definitely has to be it. I'm still a little confused though - if the device is running iOS 8, why isn't the app using the the new color scheme?  I realize it's due to the fact it was developed against an older API, but can you explain how it works on the new iOS? Is it because it's backward compatible - the old APIs are still supported?